# Handling files and folders

Tags: 2010, document, taxonomy, folder

In Sharepoint 2010, is there a way to limit the names that folders and files can be given, and is there a way to set criteria for any document libraries that are created by users?  Here is what I'd like to accomplish:

1. files and folders to act the same as adding wiki pages where spaces are converted to hyphens
2. set a limit on the length of the names of files and folders
3. set a newly created document library (created by users) to already have the elements required for enterprise keywords and automatically require that the keyword field be set; and force descriptions to be required on the files uploaded to those libraries

Answer (score 2):

For #1 and #2, you will want to take a look at the [ItemAdding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadding.aspx) event receiver. This event runs before the item is fully added to SharePoint. From here, you can perform a simple replace on the file name to convert spaces to hyphens, and check the length of the name. If necessary, you can cancel the add (see the example below).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437502.aspx